# Rails NoMethodError in helper although works in debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Error:

```
undefined method `author' for nil:NilClass
```

In my helper:

```
def last_updated(group)
  g = group.last_updated_version
  debugger
  g.author.name
end
```

If I let my last_updated(group) function return group.last_updated_version, the view prints out my object as expected:

```
#<Assets::Version:0x0000000747af48>
```

And using the debugger at the point shown above, I can pull out the name

```
(rdb:1) g.author.name
"Administrator"
```

But returning group.last_updated_version.author.name results in the error.

Can anyone tell me why group.last_updated_version seems to return my object, but group.last_updated_version.author gives me the nil:NilClass error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, silly problem.  The helper last_updated() is used in a loop.  My method last_updated_version returned nil for some of the group objects it was passed, but not the first.  The debugger obviously stops on the first, so it worked in the debugger, but then broke on groups passed after that.